# Is there any significance of reserving 256 minor numbers when dynamically assigning a major number using register_chrdev?

Tags: c, linux

Is there a significance for assigning 256 minor numbers for dynamically assigned major number using register_chrdev function

1. To dynamically assign a major number I use register_chrdev function defined in kernel

   ```
   static inline int register_chrdev(unsigned int major, const char *name,
                             const struct file_operations *fops)
   {
           return __register_chrdev(major, 0, 256, name, fops);
   }
   ```
2. __register_chrdev now will assign a dynamic major number if value of major passed as argument is 0.This particular operation has following source code in kernel

   ```
   if (major == 0) {
           for (i = ARRAY_SIZE(chrdevs)-1; i > 0; i--) {
                   if (chrdevs[i] == NULL)
                   break;
           }
   ```
3. chrdev is an array of pointers to struct char_device_struct
       *chrdevs[CHRDEV_MAJOR_HASH_SIZE];
4. Macro CHRDEV_MAJOR_HASH_SIZE is of size 255

5.ARRAY_SIZE(chrdevs) will return the size of *chrdevs array which turns out to be 5334 (pardon my wrong math calculations) considering size of struct char_device_struct is 84 bytes.

Question: This very well may be a stupid question to ask but is there a significance why exactly 256 minor numbers are assigned automatically?

Above source snipped is from linux-3.6.7 kernel
File: fs/char_dev.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register_chrdev is older interface which used to provide the 256 minors by default.
This is carried from older kernels and maintained for backword compatibility.
In new kernels from 2.6 onwards you have register_chrdev_region or alloc_chrdev_region .
In this you can specify the number of minors you need.
This is better interface to use rather than register_chrdev.